# Typescript: Partial interface with keys supplied by array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm programming against a web api that, for some of the fields, only returns them if you specify them in the query.

```
{a:"hello", b:"world", c:"of goo", d:"i am always present"}
```

and I called

```
api.getResponse(["a","b"])
```

I would get

```
{a:"hello", b:"world", d:"i am always present"}
```

in response.

How do i express that in the type language of typescript?

Comment: What is you expected outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the always present and optional fields on separate interfaces then use `Pick` to choose the correct ones:

```
interface AlwaysPresentFields {
    d: string;
}

interface OptionalFields {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}

type ApiResponse<F extends keyof OptionalFields> = AlwaysPresentFields & Pick<OptionalFields, F>;

function getResponse<F extends keyof OptionalFields>(fields: F[]): ApiResponse<F> {
    // Implementation
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

In Advanced typesscript we can use Partial, Pick, Readonly.

As in your case, ***keyof , Partial*** can be used. The same can be implemented in using **Pick** too: [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

```
interface IResponse {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  d: string;
}

const getResponse = (responseKeys: Array<keyof IResponse>): Partial<IResponse> => {
  const responseWithFilteredKeys: Partial<IResponse> = {};
  const response: IResponse = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'a',
    c: 'a',
    d: 'a',
  };
  responseKeys.forEach((key: keyof IResponse) => {
    responseWithFilteredKeys[key] = response[key];
  });
  return responseWithFilteredKeys;
};

const filterdUserResponse: Partial<IResponse> = getResponse(['a', 'b']);
```